# How to show an ImageButton hidden by keyboard - Android

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a layout that contains an EditText and an ImageButton below. When the EditText get the focus, the keyboard appears and hides the ImageButton. How can I force it to be shown, the same way as an EditText is forced to be shown if hidden by keyboard?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `"android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize"` in your manifest. You can find details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: That resize the whole layout, that's not what I want. I just want to push up the layout in order to see my ImageButton.